# How to validate a value in codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to validate the value of a input field, using the codeigniter form validation,

here's my setup_rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country_id', 'Country ID', 'required|min_length[5]');
```

Now i want to validate so that the value won't be zero

How can I accomplish that?

```
NOTE: I dont want to use any callback_function in the setup rules.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding `is_natural_no_zero` to the validation rules? Assuming the ID you refer to is only going to be a number

[Rules](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference)

> is_natural_no_zero - Returns FALSE if the form element contains
>   anything other than a natural number, but not zero: 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very simple you need to just add rule of `is_natural_no_zero`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country_id', 'Country ID', 'required|min_length[5]|');
```